# Filter related entity in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

[SETTINGS]

- Symfony 3
- ContainerEntity: [id, name]

  - Can contain 0,n BoxEntity
- BoxEntity: [id, container_id, parent, name]

  - Is always associated to a ContainerEntity
  - Can contain 0,n BoxEntity

[DATABASE CONTENT]

<kbd>container</kbd>

```
------------------
| id |    name   |
------------------
|  1 | container |
------------------
```

<kbd>box</kbd>

```
--------------------------------------
| id | container_id | parent | name  |
--------------------------------------
|  1 |            1 |   null | box 1 |
--------------------------------------
|  2 |            1 |   null | box 2 |
--------------------------------------
|  3 |            1 |      1 | box 3 |
--------------------------------------
```

[FILES]

<kbd>inventory.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% if container.box|length > 0 %}
    {% for box in container.box %}
        <li class="nav_menu_item">
            <a class="nav_menu_link" href="">{{ box.name }}</a>
            {% if box.inbox|length > 0 %}
                <div class="nav_menu_dropdown">
                    <ul>
                        {% for inbox in box.inbox %}
                            <li class="nav_menu_dropdown_item">
                                <a class="nav_menu_dropdown_link" href="">{{ inbox.name }}</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

[PROBLEM]

In twig, I would like to filter the related entity list based on it's `parent` parameter.
Currently, doing `{{ container.box|length }}` will return 3 box (same problem with `{% for ... %}`)

How can I get all `container.box` where `box.parent` is null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
{% for box in container.box if box.parent is null %}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can it also be done with `{{ container.box|length }}`? If so, how please?

Comment: {{ container.box }} contains all the box entities  without distinct which one has null or not null parent   ,  so you should distinct them with loop for.

Comment: I thought so as well. Thanks for the clarification.